# Counting HTML Elements on external webpages e.g. msn.com, yahoo.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I am working on a Google Extension that would count the number of HTML elements present on a webpage. I've been able to make a script that can count HTML elements on my "userDefined" webpages but how do I make the script work on external webpages like 
msn.com, yahoo.com or any other website ?

Please help me out in this.

Thank you.

Comment: YQL sometimes lets you turn a site's html into jsonp. it depends on header and crossdomain.xml to allow it, so some big-buck sites block it. you'll have to try and if that doesn't work, you need a server.

Comment: So YQL can help me create a cross-domain Ajax request ?

Comment: more or less, if to you jsonp==ajax, which it does to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I finally figured it out. The details are on this page:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html
You have to set permissions for the websites if you want to target specific pages or you can simply put

https://*/*
for the whole web it's your choice.

then simply by using the content script, load

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse){
```

and put the

```
document.getElementbyId() or $(" ").length
```

if you're using JQuery
This will in terms calculate the DOM objects where the content script is injected.